# keep view always square with width=fill_parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android layout with width=fill_parent I want to always have Width=Height How can I do this? wherever I check the width equals to 0. where can I see the actual width and set it to the height?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  // get width here


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imo the simplest way to have a squared layout is to subclass it and `override` its `onMeasure` method. For instance

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}
```

Comment: How will that help me? its actually an item that is in a listview

Comment: onMeasure it is called to determine the size requirements for this view and all of its children.

Comment: So check the screen size then and set the width and the height?

Comment: why the screen size ? you want to have width == height? I'll suggest you go take a look of the documentation and do a little bit of research in order to understand if it what you are looking for.

Comment: I want it to take all the screen width and then get height=width (I am talking only about portrait mode).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method and get the width of the curresponding view and can add the height of the view dynamically through the code.

```
view.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
       //Do it here
       LinearLayout layoutGet=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.GameField1);
       LayoutParams layParamsGet= layoutGet.getLayoutParams();
       int width=layParamsGet.width;
    }
    });
```

Add the height after that for the corresponding view.